# How to set up Plotly.js for WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, plotly, webstorm

I'm working on a website using JavaScript (first time I've tried).  I need a graph for it and am using Plotly.js.  However, I am getting messages such as "Unresolved method or function" for require() and "'var' used instead of 'let' or 'const'", in addition to the program saying Plotly isn't imported.

Could someone help me out with where I'm going wrong or direct me to a source that may help me work this out?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Include Plotly.js --><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title> IOT webpage w/real time graph </title>
</head>

<script>
    var plotly = require('plotly')("jhharvey", "••••••••••")

    var trace = {
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        y: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64],
        mode: 'line'
    };

    var data = [ trace ];
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. to get `require()` and other Node.js core methods resolved, please make sure to enable **Coding assistance for Node.js** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**
2. to get rid of  "'var' used instead of 'let' or 'const'" warnings, either disable the **JavaScript | ECMAScript 6 migration aids | 'var' used instead of 'let' or 'const'** inspection in **Settings | Editor | Inspections** or change **Javascript Language version** to *ECMAScript 5.1* in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**

Note that `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);` should be `Plotly.plot('myDiv', data);` (there is no `newPlot()` method in Plotly, as far as i can check). And you need changing the case in variable name - you import the module as `plotly` and then refer to it as `Plotly`